# Understanding SQL CURSOR statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Can someone please explain what the INSERTED means after FROM? there is no INSERTED Table in the trigger which has this below sql. Does the INSERTED refer to the table which has the trigger?

```
  DECLARE ChgCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ACCID,USERID,GCID,........ FROM INSERTED
  SELECT  @ppid = ppid FROM sysdba.SYSTEMINFO WHERE SYSTEMINFOID = 'PR111'
```

Answer (score 2):

A SQL Server trigger has two **pseudo** tables:

- `Inserted` which contains the newly inserted rows (in an `INSERT` trigger) or the updated (new) values in an `UPDATE` trigger
- `Deleted`, which contains the rows that were deleted (in a `DELETE` trigger), or the old values (before the update) in an `UPDATE` trigger

Both tables are present *only* within triggers and will have the identical columns as the underlying table they're "connected" to (by means of the trigger being defined *on a table*).

SQL Server triggers will be fired **once per statement** (not once per row) and thus if any of the statements affects multiple rows, then `Inserted` and/or `Deleted` *will* contain **multiple rows** - you always need to keep this in mind and code your triggers accordingly.

See more details e.g. here [Data Points: Exploring SQL Server triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx)

And a word of warning: a trigger in SQL Server should *always* be very lean and mean - do **NOT** do extended and time consuming processing in a trigger, and this also means try to avoid **cursors** in a trigger at least twice as hard as you should in other T-SQL code.